# posts_per_page is displaying 2 less items than intended

Tags: php, wordpress

my first question here, so I'm sorry if I do something wrong :S

I have a custom post type, called "portfolio", and a template which I'm using to display these posts. Unfortunately, when using posts_per_page, the template is constantly displaying 2 less items than I input. Here is what I have thus far:

```
<?php
     $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
     $args= array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => '4');
     query_posts($args);
     if( have_posts() ) :
 ?>
```

It then continues into the while loop for posting the results. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  to reset your query before your code.

```
wp_reset_query();
query_posts($args);
```

Function refrence: [wp_reset_query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query)

Comment: That fixed it! Out of interest, why is that? Why was this causing an issue? I assumed it would be reset by default?

Comment: Yeah it reset your previous query specially used in loop.

Comment: @LambrosPhotios -  Also, please don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the check-mark to the left of it :)

Comment: Done! Thank you, I'm very new here :)